# ListView set custom check Image

Tags: android, listview, android-imageview

I have one ListView and in there are 3 Rows.

My functionality is when i click on first row at that time first row contain check image and that visible true. and other 2 Rows that check image visible false.

In this code only last row's check image visible.
**Code:**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);

            String selectItem = (String) text.getText();

            for (int i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); i++) {

                ImageView checkImg = (ImageView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.select_img);

                //checkImg[position];
                //checkImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if (i == position) {
                     Log.e("Num", position + "Hi" + i + "");
                     checkImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else {
                    checkImg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            }

            // String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

        }
    });
```

Thanks,
Dharmik

Comment: why not use listView choice mode?

Comment: Is it possible to get like checkImg[0],checkImg[1],checkImg[2] If i click on 0 than i just make first visible true ?

Comment: better way is change in your adapter.for example at the same time just one row selected so define variable in your adapter and in OnItem click change it's value and notify adapter then in getView method set selected which row that value was equal to thats variable

Comment: if you want this tell to put code

Comment: Ya, Please share with me the code

Comment: @DHARMIK : you can try this [tutorial Selecting multiple items in the ListView](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) or [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013227/listview-checkbox/25013826#25013826)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create custom adapter

```
public class MAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
private LayoutInflater  inflater;
private Context         context;
 int selectedPosition = -1;
List<String> objects;
public MAdapter(Context ctx,List<String> objects) {
    super(ctx, objects);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from( ctx );
    this.context=ctx;
    this.objects=objects;
}

 @overwrite
 public int getCount(){
     return objects.length;
 }
 public View getView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)         context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_row_for_items, parent,false);


    ImageView selected = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.s);
    if(selectedPosition == position){
        selected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else
        selected.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    return convertView;
}

}
```

and In onItemCLick

```
MAdapter = adapter = new MAdapter(this,yourArray);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            adapter.selectedPosition = position;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        // String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

    }
});
```